# How to extract first two characters of a string in openpyxl Python?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to assign cell value in python openpxl by referencing the first 2nd characters of a string in another cell eg say the content of cell "A2" is the string "Random", I am trying to extract the first two characters Ra

The codes I tried so far:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('c:/Users/me/myfolder/myfile.xlsx')
ws = wb["mysheet"]

ws["A4"] = ws["A3":2]
```

I also tried

```
ws[A4]= ws["A3"]:2
```

I have also been desperate enough to try

```
ws["A4"] = LEFT(sheet["A3"],2)
```

None works

Comment: it doesn't work because you have a missing closing quotation on the file name `'`.

Comment: @ahmed AEK, that was a typo, just fixed it, my file name is fine, I am trying to figure out a way to extract the first two characters of a string with Openpxl, equivalent of excel Left(A5, 2) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [**`cell.value`**](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) property to return a string and after that, you can slice it.

Try this :

```
ws["A4"].value = ws["A3"].value[:2]
```